# Ruby: Refactoring conditional statements containing regular expressions

Tags: ruby, testing, module, refactoring

I have a single method `mock_request` that I'm overriding for unit test purposes. For each request I want to execute some code:

```
def mock_request(method, url, params={})
  case "#{method} #{url}"
  when 'post /customers'
    # create customer
  when %r{post /customers/(.*)/items}
    id = $1 # update customer
  when %r{post /customers/(.*)}
    id = $1 # update customer
  else
    throw 'Unrecognized request'
  end
end
```

The problem is that this case statement is getting quite long, and the number of lines for each case is slowly increasing. Also, several models are being handled at once.

What I would like to do is have separate files for each model, and somehow include them for use in this `mock_request` method. Something like this:

```
# handlers/customers.rb
module RequestHandlers
  # post /customers
  # post /customers/(.*)
end

# handlers/items.rb
module RequestHandlers
  # post /customers/(.*)/items
end

# mock_request.rb
class MockServer
  def mock_request(method, url, params={})
    handle_request(method, url)
  end
end
```

However I'm not exactly sure how to implement this. What's the best way to approach this in ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, here is how I ended up refactoring it.

Each 'subject' of handlers gets its own module and file:

```
module RequestHandlers
  module Customers

    def Customers.included(mock_server)
      mock_server.add_handler 'post /customers',      :new_customer
      mock_server.add_handler 'post /customers/(.*)', :update_customer
    end

    def new_customer(route, method_url, params)
      # create new customer
    end

    def update_customer(route, method_url, params)
      # update existing customer
    end

  end
end
```

The main class is where the handlers live and get used:

```
class MockServer

  # Handlers are ordered by priority
  @@handlers = []

  include RequestHandlers::Customers
  include RequestHandlers::Items
  # etc.

  def self.add_handler(route, name)
    @@handlers << {
      :route => %r{^#{route}$},
      :name => name
    }
  end

  def mock_request(method, url, params={})
    method_url = "#{method} #{url}"
    handler = @@handlers.find {|h| method_url =~ h[:route] }

    if handler
      self.send(handler[:name], handler[:route], method_url, params)
    else
      throw 'Unrecognized request'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a hash which contains the method and URL strings as your keys and the block of code you want to evaluate as the values.

```
def mock_request(method, url, params={})
 #create a request hash where the default value is your else, this way if a key that doesn't exist is called, the unrecognized request is called

  req =  Hash.new ({throw 'Unrecognized request'})
  req['post /customers'] = {#create customer block/proc}
  req[%r{post /customers/(.*)/items}] = {#update customer block/proc}

  req["#{method} #{url}"]
end
```

This could be a better option for you and would rid you of the lengthy case statement.

Comment: This was my first thought, but it doesn't work since I'm using regular expressions in the `when` conditionals.

Comment: @mindeavor use `req.find { |key, value| key === "#{method} #{url}" }` instead.

Comment: Even using req[method.scan(%r{post /customers/(.*)/items})] = {#proc} could work as well, depending on how wordy you want to be.

Comment: Nice, so I can use a hash to store the request handlers. How would I structure my code so that I can split up these handlers into multiple files? Ideally it won't have to reconstruct the hash every request.